# Sometimes Chrome doesn't execute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, ipb

I have a little problem with JavaScript. My board is running on IP.Board 3.4. Sometimes Google Chrome doesn't want to execute my JavaScript. About 4/5 months ago everything worked great. The weirdest thing is the fact that the problem occurs only on Google Chrome. JS on Firefox/Opera works perfect every time, after every page reload. I can't post any code because IP.B has too many js files and I don't know which one can cause the problem. Maybe Google Chrome is the problem, not code, as I mentioned, on the other browsers everything is perfect. What do you think? Sorry for my bad English :(.

Comment: Sure, might all be. But what do you expect from us?

Comment: Have a try to use that browsers development console. You need to catch such an incident in real life. Then you can examine it. We cannot help with that, I am afraid.

Comment: Dev console is clear. I hoped that anybody else had similar problem with JS on Chrome. Thanks for answers guys.

Comment: That sounds very strange. I suggest you start either adding debugging statements into your js code, or you step through.

Comment: Might actually be a race condition with loading and initializing resources. Take a look into the network tab in the console.

Comment: Have you disabled all chrome add-ons? Sometimes JS code won't run on a page because of a bad add-on